# Dynamically changing columns in Crystal Report 2008

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

My customer want to use Crystal Report to basically print data from DataGridViews in the application to paper or PDF.  (there are approx. 30 different DataGridViews)

They want to have the same column names in the Crystal Report view as is show in the source DataGridView and column width etc. shall also be proportional.

I tried if I could create the Crystal Report dynamically and found this article. 
http://aspalliance.com/661

But this method does not seam to be supported in newer versions. TextObject.Text is readonly. 
Does anyone know if it is possible to generate my 30 reports dynamically or simiautomated.

Comment: When you accept an answer please upvote it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to just generate pdf from the dataset and bypass crystal all together. I hear [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch05.html#pdfptable) is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use formula or parameter fields for the column titles and fill those from code.