# Dynamic columns in Crystal Report 2008

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have look through the links below:

> [Dynamically changing columns in Crystal Report 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287585/dynamically-changing-columns-in-crystal-report-2008)
>
> [Dynamic Columns in Crystal reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457881/dynamic-columns-in-crystal-reports)

However, it seems not suit my requirement.

So, basically, i have database fields that contains the following:

type_id | type_value 
1             Test1
2             Test2

So, I would like to have the crystal report generate the columns as

Test1 | Test2 
1           2

If I have changed the data as below: 
type_id | type_value 
1           Test11 
2           Test22

The crystal report columns would react automatically: 
Test11 | Test22 
1               2

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would have the pivot be done in the data source instead of Crystal Report.

1. Prepare the data table from dynamic SQL / application code doing pivot. Know the max. column you can show in the report. The output of the table like this
   `Column1Name, Column1Value, Column2Name, Column2Value...`
2. Have your report column suppress by column name if it is null.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to do it in Crystal Report instead?

Answer (score 0):

use cross tab in crystal report for that purpose.

In rows put type ID and column put type value.